# Issues rendering a Bootstrap3 table using a collection

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got an Organization view that I want to render a partial into in order to show Users of the Organization with a bunch of additional features. To do so I have a Bootstrap panel set up, and inside this panel I want to render a bootstrap Table in order to show each user that belongs_to the Organization. I can get it working fine without the table css (just as separate div elements showing one User per line), but for some reason when I come to create a Table the thing keeps building entirely new  divs for each User object. Can you help?

Organization show page html:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        <ul class="users">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading float-left">
            <% if current_user.admin? %>
            <%= link_to "Add more users", add_user_path(current_user.organization), class: "btn btn-large btn-success btn-panel" %>
            <% end %>
            <h2 class="panel-title">Users:</h2>
          </div>
            <div class="panel-body panel-height">
                <%= render partial: "users_index", collection: @users_index, as: :user %>
                <br></br>
            </div>
        </div>
        </ul>
</div>
```

The html for my users_index partial:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <%= link_to user.name, user %>
            </td>
            <td>
            <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
                <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                            data: {confirm: "You sure?" }, 
                                            class: "btn btn-sm btn-danger pull-right"%>
            <% end %>
            </td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

The place where the users_index is defined (my Organization controller show function):

```
def show
 @organization = Organization.find(params[:id])
 @users_index = @organization.users
end
```

I tried wrapping everything in a <%= users_index.each do |user| %> block, but this just prints out the full object of each user above the table header as well as the generated HTML below.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes from this line:

```
<%= render partial: "users_index", collection: @users_index, as: :user %>
```

When you render a partial as the user, it renders the entire content of the partial as if you'd put it in a loop. The solution was to take the table styling into the Organization show page, and then just keep the partial to be wrapped in  and  classes.